# Dereferencing a boost::ptr_vector

Tags: c++

So right now I have the following:

```
        boost::ptr_vector <Customer> cvect;

         ifstream cDbase("datafiles/customers.txt");

        while (cDbase.good())
        {
            while (!cDbase.eof())
            {
                cDbase >> newCust;

                Customer* c = &newCust;
                cvect.push_back(c);

            }
        }


        for (unsigned int loop = 0; loop < cvect.size(); loop++)
            {   
                cout << cvect[loop];
            }
```

When I try to print the customer details, it prints out blank lines. How do I dereference ptr_vector properly?

Comment: Your input loop is wrong. Skip the double loop, and do only `while (cDbase >> newCust) { ... }`

Comment: What is newCust? Where do you create it?

Answer (score 2):

The Boost pointer-containers are for containers which *own dynamically-allocated objects.* So to use it as intended, you'd do this:

```
while (cDbase >> newCust) {
  cvect.push_back(new Customer(newCust));
}
```

(Note: [never loop on `eof()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/1782465)).

However, do you really need to store them dynamically? How about simply this:

```
std::vector<Customer> cvect;

ifstream cDbase("datafiles/customers.txt");

while (cDbase >> newCust) {
  cvect.push_back(newCust);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `newCust` is a local variable, you push a pointer to a local variable into the vector which will not work.

Instead you have to create a new object each time through the loop. A simple solution would look something like this:

```
while (cDbase >> newCust)
    cvect.push_back(new Customer(newCust));
```

This might require you to have a proper copy-constructor in place.